# Звуковые уведомления в браузере об ответах и комментариях

Tags: обсуждение, уведомления

Не помешали бы, когда работаешь/занимаешься своими делами, не находясь в данную минуту ни на одном из сайтов Stack Exchange, а тебе кто-то ответил. Можно ли как-то подключить таковые? мой браузер — Pale Moon (поддерживает темы, расширения и плагины Firefox).

Comment: Нашел расширение [Desktop notifications for StackExchange](http://stackapps.com/questions/3780/real-time-desktop-notifications-for-stack-exchange-inbox-chrome-firefox), возможо, окажется полезным.

Comment: @soon, к сожалению, у меня работает только в 2-х случаях: при перезагрузке браузера и если нажать на «Stop», а потом снова «Start». Да и тогда в левом верхнем углу выскакивает [прямоугольник](https://i.gyazo.com/3816f3b1a17c57e6475f92c276eb15eb.png), не содержащий каких-было надписей в себе. Спасибо.

Comment: В google chrome работает без перезагрузки. В прямоугольнике, увы, не цитируется уведомление, но написано, что в inbox есть одно непрочитанное сообщение.

Answer (score 3):

использую в качестве «звукового оповещателя» телефон с [*dalvik/linux*](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android) «на борту» и официальным клиентом [so] (все иные функции клиента, увы, «неюзабельны»).

вот [*здесь*](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/154797/298597) перечислены наиболее популярные клиентские программы для разных платформ.

Comment: Вот да - офиц. клиент только для оповещений и годится. Всё остальное - мрак, юзать невозможно( Лелею мечту как-нить заняться написанием собственного с нардами и гражданскими активистками)

Comment: @ЮрийСПб Пишите, Юрий, пишите!

Comment: @NickVolynkin, одна из многих причин, что всё ещё меня останавливает - я плохо понимаю как программно залогиниться тут у нас(

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, https://api.stackexchange.com/docs, в частности: https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/authentication

Comment: @alexanderbarakin, я про это знаю) Просто пару лет назад я пытался на каком-то сайте (не SE) залогиниться... У меня ничего и не вышло и теперь я впадаю в депрессию при одной мысли о логине на к-л сайте)))